# no messages consumed from queue

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I am trying to consume the message from `Amazon SQS` using `camel`.

```
<from uri="aws-sqs://{{aws.sqs.queue}}?amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient&amp;delay=10000"/>
<to uri="bean:sqsQueueListener?method=consumeMessage(${body})"/>
```

The handler looks like this (I originally did not specify it in `xml` because annotation should have handle it but it did not work so I defined it directly)

```
class SqsQueueListener { 
    @Handler
    public void consumeMessage(List<Message> messages) {
        LOGGER.info("Got messages: [{}].", messages);
    }
}
```

Every `10 seconds` I get the message regarding instantiation of `AmazonSQS` client in my application as it is trying to read from queue. But nothing happens then. I don't get the message about consumed messages.

What is the problem?

Comment: Are there any messages to be consumed from the queue?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your handler to the registry attached to the camel context with the name "sqsClient"?

Comment: Yes. I am using spring so It should have got the bean from the applicatio context